# Getting 404 Nginx error page for React Router

Tags: reactjs, nginx, deployment, hosting, vps

I created a react app that contains different routes using react router. Everything seems to work on my local machine but once I add it to my Hostinger VPS I keep getting a 404 error. I followed all the possible solutions related to this issue on here and other sources but with no luck. Here is what my setup looks like:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domainName

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com www.domainName.com;

root /var/www/domainName;
index index.html index.htm;
location / {
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

App.js

```
import Main from "./containers/Main";
import Theme from "./actions/Theme";
import MenuToggle from "./actions/MenuToggle";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";
import ProjectDetail from "./containers/projects/ProjectDetail";
import Projects from "./containers/Projects";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  // website theme
  const { theme, changeTheme } = Theme();

  // hamburger menu
  const { toggleMenu } = MenuToggle();

  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route errorElement={<NotFound />} status={404}>
        <Route
          index
          element={
            <Main
              theme={theme}
              changeTheme={changeTheme}
              toggleMenu={toggleMenu}
            />
          }
        />
        <Route path="projects">
          <Route index element={<Projects />} />
          <Route path=":id" index element={<ProjectDetail />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    )
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="overlay" onClick={toggleMenu}></div>
      <div className="grain"></div>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am getting the nginx 404 page. I am able to see the hostname.com/ I came to the conclusion the problem is with the configuration file but everything seems right. I am able to see the app but not it's routes for example hostname.com is visible but not hostname.com/projects. I know the react router should redirect it to read from the index.html since react router works by switching out the html code using js as compared to looking for specific html files within the directory.

The try_files should fix this but neither the routes or the custom 404 page I created are visible. I tried most common solutions found on stackoverflow and other places. What I expected to happen was be able to see my routes in the build version of my react application but I keep getting the nginx 404 page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it hitting the correct server?  What is in the access log and the error log?